# Include file from parent directory in tar file using gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a `nodejs` application, directory structure setup as follows:

```
.
├── api
│   └── swagger
│       └── swagger.yaml
└── service
    ├── app.js
    ├── build.gradle
    ├── lib
    │   └── utils.js
    └── package.json
```

Here is a snippet from `build.gradle` which attempts to create a `tar` of required files ..

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

def jsLib = 'lib/'
def packageJson = 'package.json'
def swagger = '../api/swagger/swagger.yaml'
def appJs = 'app.js'

task pack(type: Tar) {
    from(project.projectDir)
    include(packageJson)
    include(swagger)
    include(jsLib)
    include(appJs)
    baseName rootProject.name + '.' + project.name
    version rootProject.version
    compression = Compression.GZIP
    extension = 'tgz'
}
```

This partially works, the resulting `tar` contains everything except `swagger.yaml` which is in the parent directory to `service/`.

How could this file be included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
task pack(type: Tar) {
    from(project.projectDir)
    include(packageJson)
    include(jsLib)
    include(npmrc)
    include(newrelic)
    include(appJs)
    include(config)
    from (project.parent.projectDir)
    include('api/swagger/swagger.yaml')
    baseName rootProject.name + '.' + project.name
    version rootProject.version
    compression = Compression.GZIP
    extension = 'tgz'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If both `service` and `api` are 1.) subprojects of a parent project or 2.) part of more complicated subproject hierarchy, you can use:

```
1.) from(project.parent.projectDir) {
    include **/*.yaml
}

2.) from(project.rootProject.projectDir) {
    include **/*.yaml
}
```

If not, you have to explicitly specify the directory:

```
def apiDir = new File(project.parent.projectDir.parentFile, "api")
from(apiDir) {
    include **/*.yaml
}
```